# Drupal 8.6 Form from entity in controller

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm trying to create the form from Entity in the controller.

This is the code of controller:

```
class OutOfOfficeController extends ControllerBase
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $event = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('event')->create(['type' => 'out_of_office']);
        $form  = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($event);
        return $form;
    }
}
```

And this is the error which I get:

> Error: Call to a member function getTranslationFromContext() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm->initFormLangcodes() (line 313 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityForm.php).

- It seems that the ContentEntityForm do not have any dependencies
- In ContentEntityForm the `$this->entityRepository` returns `null`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with `Event` entity itself.

The `Event` entity was referring to `EventForm`, which had a constructor which overrides the `ContentEntityForm`. The problem is fixed when __constructor was removed from `EventForm`